# Matlab simulate(MDL) python equivalent

Tags: python, matlab, stochastic

I am trying to simulate a stochastic differential equation (SDE) model. I've used the `sdeint` package (Ito method) in order to generate the timestep solutions for my model.
Now I am looking for a python alternative to the matlab `[Paths,Times,Z] = simulate(MDL)` method (only interested in the first two outputs: paths and times).

Python code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import sdeint

# the drift and diffusion functions are defined elsewhere in my code
F = lambda x, t: drift(x, t)
G = lambda x, t: diffusion(x, t)

t = np.linspace(0, 20, nPeriods)
x0 = np.array([0.006, 5.05, 0.07, 29.78]) # initial condition

SDE = sdeint.itoint(F, G, x0, t)
```

Matlab inspiration:

```
SDE = sde(F,G,'StartState', x0);
[S,T] = simulate(SDE, nPeriods, 'DeltaTime', dt);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which `simulate` command are you trying to replicate? The Mathworks documentation suggests that the simulate command is present in at least two toolboxes for example "Econometrics" and "Risk Management"

Comment: Not quite sure if I get your question right (and I am not familiar with toolboxes in matlab). My project has to do with population dynamics. I see that the command I am looking at is at the financial toolbox (link: https://www.mathworks.com/help/finance/sde.simulate.html).